# emberjs arraycontroller not sorting

Tags: ember.js

I have reviewed many examples but I can't seem to make my ArrayController sort!
I have: (fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6bphs4h7/1/)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="usergroups">
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>{{name}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>

var App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.UsergroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return [ 
        Ember.Object.create({id: 1, name: 'foo'}), 
        Ember.Object.create({id: 2, name: 'bar'}) 
    ];
  }
});

App.UsergroupsGroupsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name'],
  sortAscending: true,
});

App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('usergroups', {path: '/'});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because your controller is different than the route with the model?

```
App.UsergroupsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name'],
  sortAscending: true,
});
```

Your controller was for `UsergroupsGroups` when it should be `Usergroups`.

Comment: here is a bin showing it working correctly once changed to `UsergroupsController`. See: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/moxape/1/edit

Comment: sigh... I have spent days looking at this piece of code. Thanks. I need a smarter ide (or coder). Thanks.

Comment: @user3746371 You need the Ember debugger plugin for Chrome.  This shows your view hierarchy and which controllers and models are being used for each.